# R ggplot scale_y_log10, remove 10^(-0.5) from log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the following code to get a log scale on my axis, however, it also displays intermediate values like 10^(0.5), 10^(1.5), 10^(2.5)... How can I get rid of those and only show the full 10^1, 10^2,..., as my axis labels?

```
scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
            labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try playing with the `n` argument to `scales::breaks_log` (the default is `n=5`), as in

```r
scale_y_log10(breaks = breaks_log(n=3))
```

Or if you are willing to hard-code the solution for a particular graph you could use

```r
scale_y_log10(breaks = 10^(1:3))
```

once you've established the range you want.